# Log4j2 markers in Logback

Tags: java, logging, logback, log4j2, log4jdbc

I'd like to use [log4jdbc-log4j2](https://code.google.com/archive/p/log4jdbc-log4j2/) to log JDBC calls. The documentation providers information how to use it with Log4j2 markers.

```
<logger name="log4jdbc.log4j2" level="info" additivity="false">
  <MarkerFilter marker="LOG4JDBC_OTHER" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
  <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
</logger>
```

**Is there any way how to rewrite the above code to work with Logback?**

**UPDATE**: I already tried to put a TurboFilter outside the logger directly inside the configuration element. It however doesn't change the log output.

```
<turboFilter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.turbo.MarkerFilter">
    <Name>LOG4JDBC_LOGBACK_FILTER</Name>
    <Marker>LOG4JDBC_OTHER</Marker>
    <OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch>
</turboFilter>
```

Answer (score 2):

Markers in log4j2 work this way:

```
package org.so.log4j2.test;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Marker;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.MarkerManager;

public class Log4j2Test {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("Test");
        Marker LOG4JDBC_OTHER = MarkerManager.getMarker("LOG4JDBC_OTHER");

        logger.info("Line to show.");
        logger.info(LOG4JDBC_OTHER, "Line to hide");
    }
}
```

With below log4j2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <MarkerFilter marker="LOG4JDBC_OTHER" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
        <Logger name="Test" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Output:

```
12:37:22.416 [main] INFO  Test - Line to show.
```

Markers in Logback work this way:

```
package org.so.logback.test;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.slf4j.Marker;
import org.slf4j.MarkerFactory;

public class LogbackTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("Test");
        Marker LOG4JDBC_OTHER = MarkerFactory.getMarker("LOG4JDBC_OTHER");
        logger.info("Line to show");
        logger.info(LOG4JDBC_OTHER, "Line to hide");
    }
}
```

With this logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<configuration>
    <property name="log.folder" value="./log"/>
    <turboFilter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.turbo.MarkerFilter">
        <Marker>LOG4JDBC_OTHER</Marker>
        <OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch>
        <OnMismatch>NEUTRAL</OnMismatch>
    </turboFilter>

  <appender class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender" name="CONSOLE">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>[%p] [%thread] %logger - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root>
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
  </root>

  <logger name="Test" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
  </logger>     
</configuration>
```

Output:

```
[INFO] [main] Test - Line to show
```

Hope it helps.

P.s. maybe *additivity* flag again?..

Comment: I'm able to get an example with my own ```MarkerFactory.getMarker``` working as you have it in #2. However it doesn't work with the log4jdbc-log4j2 because it uses org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger (example #1) and I use logback.xml (example #2).

Comment: What do you want to achieve in the end? Single XML config file combining both -- logback and log4jdbc-log4j2 settings?

Comment: I'm trying to configure this with single xml config file however  don't mind number of files. I want output to console and one file for both my app and the library.

Comment: Can you switch log4jdbc to slf4j ?  Quote from project: " The name of this project is slightly misleading, as it also supports SLF4J, which implicitly supports every major logging framework."

Comment: I'm able to get logging work as needed with slf4j as described in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37087547/398861). I just cannot make it work with the Markers.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to put `log4jdbc.dump.sql.select=false` in log4jdbc.log4j2.properties, and it filtered out select statements. You can replace 'select' with other key words like 'create', 'update'...

If you want to have more control on the logging, you can extend `Slf4jSpyLogDelegator`, point `log4jdbc.spylogdelegator.name` to your new class and override methods as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is called TurboFilters in Logback. See http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html

Update: if I understand your question correctly, you have an application that uses the Log4j 2 API (or one of its dependencies does). You want to use Logback as the logger implementation. Now, the question is, how to route calls from the Log4j 2 API to the Logback implementation, ideally translating Log4j 2 Markers into SLF4J Markers?

Perhaps all you need to do is add the [Log4j to SLF4J adapter](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-to-slf4j/index.html) (log4j-to-slf4j-2.x.jar).

Be careful:

> Use of the SLF4J adapter (log4j-to-slf4j-2.x.jar) together with the
>   SLF4J bridge (log4j-slf4j-impl-2.x.jar) should never be attempted as
>   it will cause events to endlessly be routed between SLF4J and Log4j 2.

Comment: Thanks for prompt answer. I already tried it before posting my question and it didn't work for me. I've updated my question. I'm not sure if I can simply use the log4j2 marker name that the library uses.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. The dependency ```log4jdbc-log4j2``` uses Log4j 2 API and I use ```spring-boot-starter``` with ```logback```. I tried to add dependency to ```org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:2.5``` but it doesn't filter anything, I still see all the messages in console.

Comment: That's strange. Looking at the code, log4j-to-slf4j does try to convert the Markers: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-to-slf4j/xref/org/apache/logging/slf4j/SLF4JLogger.html#L92

Comment: Perhaps you still see log4j2 output in the console because the log4j2 implementation jar (log4j-core) is still in the classpath? (You only need log4j-api and log4j-to-slf4j)

Comment: I don't have log4j-core among dependencies. I have ```logback-core``` and ```logback-classic```. Spring Boot adds  ```org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.7.16```` which redirects log4j calls to slf4j. I also added ```org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:2.5``` as you suggested. In additional to that I also see following dependencies ```org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.4.1```,  ```org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.16```, ```org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.16```, ```org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.16```.

Comment: What level are the messages you're seeing? ERROR?

Comment: I see INFO level messages.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in logback.xml. This doesn't use markers at all but does what I need i.e. filters only sql statements (with timing).

```
<logger name="jdbc.sqlonly" level="error" additivity="false" ><appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/></logger>
<logger name="jdbc.sqltiming" level="info" additivity="false" ><appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/></logger>
<logger name="jdbc.audit" level="error" additivity="false" ><appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/></logger>
<logger name="jdbc.resultset" level="error" additivity="false" ><appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/></logger>
<logger name="jdbc.resultsettable" level="info" additivity="false" ><appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/></logger>
<logger name="jdbc.connection" level="error" additivity="false" ><appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/></logger>
```

These 6 loggers are described in [log4jdbc-log4j2 documentation](https://code.google.com/archive/p/log4jdbc-log4j2/).